# Why does HTML button doesn't invoke onclick event assigned function

Tags: javascript, html

When trying to invoke a JavaScript function of a .js file from .html file the function doesn't being invoked.

Project hierarchy:

- html (folder)

  - main.html
- js (folder)

  - script.js

Example #1 - using .html - Works

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Main page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label id="label1"></label>
        <input id="text1" type="text"/>
        <button onclick="document.getElementById('label1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text1').value">Button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Example #2 - using .html and .js - Doesn't work

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Main page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label id="label1"></label>
        <input id="text1" type="text"/>
        <button onclick="outputInput()">Button</button>

        <script src="/js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
function outputInput(){
    document.getElementById('label1').innerHTML = document.getElementById('text1').value;}
```

Comment: Could be several things. It would be very helpful if you checked for any error in the JavaScript console and made sure that the script is loaded.

Comment: Touffy thank you for your answer, how could I check for JavaScript errors? I'm using WebStorm by the way.

Comment: Open your webpage in a browser. Depending on the browser you may have to enable dev tools. Then find where your browser has the developer tools / JavaScript console / WebKit inspector… the console will probably also show you if there was a 404 error when trying to retrieve the script.

Comment: Touffy thank you for your replay, I navigated to "script" tab when inspecting elements while running the .html and the following error occurred: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. I am using Chrome.

Comment: Well then, I suspect that your absolute URL in the `src` attribute is the culprit. Try "../js/script.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `<script src="/js/script.js"></script>`, you're using an absolute URL. Based on further testing, it appears that your "js" folder is not at the root of your website and so it is not found there. Using a relative URL `src="../js/script.js"` is more tolerant about where you put things.